# JsonB and attr_json gem: Get the defined attributes programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using a jsonb field in my Rails application and have installed the [gem attr_json](https://github.com/jrochkind/attr_json). Is there a way to receive the defined json_attributes programmatically? With a "normal" rails attribute, I would just do @instance.attribute_names. But with attr_json is there any way how to have the json_attributes returned?

```
class Vehicle < Item
  include AttrJson::Record

  attr_json :licence_plate, :string, container_attribute: "custom_attributes_indexed"
  attr_json :brand, :string, container_attribute: "custom_attributes_indexed"
  attr_json :serial_number, :string, container_attribute: "custom_attributes_indexed"
  attr_json :inventory_number, :string, container_attribute: "custom_attributes_indexed"
end
```

For this code I would like to do something like @vehicle.json_attribute_names and have the following returned

```
["licence_plate", "brand", "serial_number", "inventory_number"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the defined json_attributes via: `Vehicle.attr_json_registry.attribute_names`

But even simpler to retrieve the attributes via the rails method `attribute names` is to add `rails_attribute: true` to your attr_json definitions. This will return all the "normal" attributes and the JSON attributes as an array.

```
[...]
attr_json :licence_plate, :string, container_attribute: "custom_attributes_indexed", rails_attribute: true
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Rails app that uses a JSONB column in Postgres and without any other gems I can call the following to get the keys...

Given a model `Inspections` with a JSONB column called "results" I can do:

```
@some_inspection = Inspection.first
@some_inspection.results
  #=> {"assigned_to" => "John Smith", "inspection_date" => "2020_01_02", "passed" => "true"}

@some_inspection.results.keys
  #=> ["assigned_to", "inspection_date", "passed"]
```

I was under the impression that the great thing about having a JSONB column is that it seamlessly translates for me. I don't have any `attr_json` nor any other specialized code in my model. Like so much Ruby and Rails "it just works". I pass it a hash and it stores that as JSON and when I ask for it, I get a hash. I can then do any hash methods like `.values` or `.keys` on it. If I need JSON back I can do `@some_inspection.results.to_json`.

If you pass it actual JSON then it will just store the JSON text as a string in the column. You can then get the JSON back just by calling the column name like:

```
@some_inspection.results
  #=> "{\"assigned_to\":\"John Smith\",\"inspection_date\":\"2020_01_02\",\"passed\":\"true\"}"
```

But if you want to do something like `.keys` you have to parse it since it is a string:

```
JSON.parse(@some_inspection.results).keys
  #=> ["assigned_to", "inspection_date", "passed"]
```

Comment: Hi, true, but this extensions provides attribute type casts, which is especially usefull when storing and retrieving dates (also for localizing). Further jsonb can be a bit of a pain to work with with form_helpers (like text_field helpers, etc.). But I got a different solution (from the developer of the gem), he will post the answer here shortly.